# python re.match list of regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have two lists: `ignorelist` which is a list of regular expressions, and another list called`urllist`. I am trying to make it so if an index item  in `urllist` matches a regular expression in `ignorelist`, it will not get added to `finallist`

```
ignorelist = ['(?:\.)amazon\.com(?:\/(?:.*))',
            '(?:\.)google\.com(?:\/(?:.*))']

urllist = ['api.amazon.com/', 'fakedomain.com/']
finallist = []

for r in ignorelist:
    r = re.compile(r)
    finallist = [x for x in urllist if not r.match(x)]
```

which outputs

```
['api.amazon.com/', 'fakedomain.com/']
```

I'm trying to make the output basically be `['fakedomain.com/']` because it wouldn't match the regular expressions in `ignorelist`

Comment: `re.match` matches at the start of string only. Use `re.search`. Also, no need to use so many non-capturing groups if you do not quantify them. The problem is also with the ignore list loop: one regex matches amazon, and the other does not. That is why both appear in the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

several issues here:

- `re.match` searches at the start of the line. Your expressions are not built for that. Use `re.search`.
- your assigning the result in a loop: wrong logic.

I would do:

```
import re

ignorelist = ['(?:\.)amazon\.com(?:\/(?:.*))',
            '(?:\.)google\.com(?:\/(?:.*))']

urllist = ['api.amazon.com/', 'fakedomain.com/']


finallist = [x for x in urllist if not any(re.search(r,x) for r in ignorelist)]
```

so `finallist` contains only urls not matching any of the regexes of `ignorelist`

result:

```
['fakedomain.com/']
```

note that I didn't "compile" the regexes, but you may gain some speed by doing so when testing a lot of domains.

Comment: nice. I didn't stop to observe all the underlying problems with OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering for each regex of your ignore list, and then reassigning `finallist` each time. So only the last regex will be taken in account.

```
finallist = []
for url in urllist:
    if any([re.search(r, url) for r in ignorelist]):
       finallist.append(url)
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
finallist = [url for url in urllist if not any(re.search(r, url) for r in ignorelist)]
```

[See the working demo.](https://repl.it/KQCq)

Comment: good. Small detail (Wiktor comment gave the answer ages ago now I realize): `match` doesn't work with those expressions. `search` does.

Comment: Yeah I saw that also while in the docs, updated :) (http://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/re#search-vs-match)